# How to compile this SDL2 sample program?

Tags: ubuntu, make, cross-compilation, g++

I tried to build [this SDL2 sample program](https://glusoft.com/sdl2-tutorials/display-image-sdl_image/), but failed.

I made it with Makefile:

```make
CFLAGS = -I/usr/include
CC = arm-linux-g++
sdltest:        sdl2-test.cpp
        $(CC)  sdl2-test.cpp  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image $(CFLAGS) `sdl2-config  --cflags --libs` -o sdl2-test

clean:
        rm sdl2-test
```

I made it and got the below result:

```shellsession
$ arm-linux-g++  sdl2-test.cpp  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -I/usr/include  `sdl2-config  --cflags --libs` -o sdl2-test
In file included from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_stdinc.h:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_main.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:32,
                 from sdl2-test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/SDL2/SDL_config.h:4:35: fatal error: SDL2/_real_SDL_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <SDL2/_real_SDL_config.h>
                                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:4: sdltest] Error 1
```

I then changed `CFLAGS` in Makefile to

```make
CFLAGS = -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

made it and then I got such a response

```shellsession
$ arm-linux-g++  sdl2-test.cpp  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu `sdl2-config  --cflags --libs` -o sdl2-test
In file included from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38:0,
                 from sdl2-test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:102:23: fatal error: immintrin.h: No such file or directory
 #include <immintrin.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:4: sdltest] Error 1
```

I can't find `immintrin.h` under `/usr/include`.

What can I do to build such a sample program?

P.S.: I installed SDL1 mistakenly before installing SDL2 because I am new and didn't know enough about SDL. Below is my installation:

```shellsession
~/prebuilts/gcc-x64/m1/sdl/sdl2-sample$ ll /usr/include/SDL* -d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  三  13 16:37 /usr/include/SDL/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  三  13 13:56 /usr/include/SDL2/

~/prebuilts/gcc-x64/m1/sdl/sdl2-sample$ ll /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -d
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096  三  13 16:37 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//

~/prebuilts/gcc-x64/m1/sdl/sdl2-sample$ ll /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/SDL* -d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  三  13 10:14 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/SDL2/
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you’re trying to cross-compile (`CC=arm-linux-g++`)? If you compile natively everything should just work; if you really want to cross-compile you’ll have to provide the correct headers for your target platform.

Comment: It's because I would run it on the ARM-based platform, not the native one.